# Tangents in the same direction

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

I have some shape (e.g. an ellipse) with some points on it (e.g. $8$). I have plotted below these $8$ points together with $2$ vectors at each point:

- A gradient vector
- The tangent vector (or a basis spanning the tangent line)

As you can see, the tangents don't follow the same "direction", i.e. clockwise or counterclockwise. I am not sure why that's the case but that's fine. Is there a way to take a set of tangent vectors like this and transform them so that they all point "in the same direction" i.e. either all clockwise or counterclockwise?

[image]

Comment: A quite interesting way would be to embed the plane in which the shape is given into a three-dimensional space. Now you can define the normal vector of the shape. To get the tangent vectors, you have to calculate the cross product of the normal vector and the gradient vector. These now should all point into the same direction.

Comment: @max_121 Great idea! That would only work in $2D$ though..any change this can be done in larger dimentions? in that case we'd have N-1 tangent basis vectors but the principle would be the same

Comment: @max_121 In this 3D embedding, I don't see the difference between the normal vector and the gradient vector. Besides, why would it be necessary to work in 3D whereas there are solutions in 2D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Consider the case of the ellipse, but the principle is valid in fact for any curve (as one can see on the second figure $(x(t)=k \cos(3t),y(t)=k \sin(t))$).

Let us start from the parametrized representation:

$$\begin{cases}x(t)&=&a \cos(t)\\y(t)&=&b \sin(t)\end{cases}$$

Take the **unit** tangent vector:

$$T=\begin{cases}x'(t)/n(t)&=&-a \sin(t)/n(t)\\y'(t)/n(t)&=& \ \ \ b \cos(t)/n(t)\end{cases} \ \  \text{where} \ \ \ n(t)=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}$$

and take this unit normal vector to T (we have the choice between this one and its opposite):

$$N=\begin{cases} \ \ y'(t)/n(t)&=&b \cos(t)/n(t)\\-x'(t)/n(t)&=&a \sin(t)/n(t)\end{cases}$$

In this way, basis $(N,T)$ is direct. Indeed:

$$\det(N,T)=\begin{vmatrix}\ \ \ y'(t)/n(t)&x'(t)/n(t)\\-x'(t)/n(t)&y'(t)/n(t) \end{vmatrix}=(y'(t)^2+x'(t)^2)/n(t)^2=1$$